# order_by with multiple criteria causes distinct to misbehave

Tags: django, database, orm, sql-order-by

```
class Titlecomplaint(models.Model):
    title= models.ForeignKey("titles.title", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    user= models.ForeignKey("auth.user", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

From the model above I need to get only one copy of every title, while sorting titles by the amount of title. When the amount is equal, I want to sort by "created_date".

```
the_titles= Titlecomplaint.objects.values_list('title', flat=True).distinct().annotate(cnt=Count("title")).order_by("-cnt")
```

But when I add a second order_by criteria as shown below, distinct() stops working and returns all the model instances without removing duplicates.

```
the_titles= Titlecomplaint.objects.values_list('title', flat=True).distinct().annotate(cnt=Count("title")).order_by("-cnt","created_date")
```

Comment: What is `Titleispit`?

Comment: Well that's normal, since it will imply "destroy" the group by. If there are multiple `title`s that are the same, but with a different `create_date`, then *which* `create_date` should be picked?

Comment: Edited, sorry about that it's a Turkish slang for "snitch" :D

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right I didn't think that way, what about getting an avarage date?